# Is it possible to downgrade a AWS RDS from mysql 5.7 to lower version (say 5.6)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

This is something i need to figure out, my company runs a number of prod RDS on AWS. Some of the mysql RDS run with 5.7 , i need to downgrade the mysql to 5.6 or 5.5 . Is this functionality provided by AWS.

```
Scenario: A mysql server already up and running with mysql version 5.7, Downgrade this to 5.6 

        -> If this is possible then what are the possible ways ?
        -> How to do this ?
```

Comment: there is no support to downgrade it , can u be sure of it?

Comment: *Why* do you need to downgrade? What actual problem do you think may be solved by downgrading?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is something specific to the app that i am running

Comment: Good question, it might be worth considering fixing application compatibility rather than downgrading DB engine @Kittystone, definitely less risky.

Comment: @Kittystone shouldn't you fix *the root* problem then, instead of downgrading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not something that AWS provides out of the box, however it can be solved with below 2 approaches depending on your database size and downtime that you can accept.

It might worth considering fixing application compatibility instead of downgrading DB which is more risky operation.

**1. Dump, restore and switch method**

Dump your currently running database with `mysqldump` utility. Start a new RDS instance with downgraded engine, load your dumped data into it. Switch your application to use RDS instance with downgraded engine.

**2. Dump, restore, replicate & switch method**

Dump your currently running database with `mysqldump` utility. Start a new RDS instance with downgraded MySQL engine, load your dumped data into it.
Set the new, downgraded DB instance as read replica of your old DB instance using `mysql.rds_set_external_master` and then start replication using `mysql.rds_start_replication`. Stop writes to your original DB, once the read replica catches up (you must monitor replication lag), run `mysql.rds_reset_external_master` which will promote your downgraded instance and turn off replication. Point your application to the downgraded RDS DB instance.

Method 2 will shorten your downtime to minimum, but is a bit more complex to execute. Here is a command reference to get familiar with to help you succeed: [MySQL on Amazon RDS SQL Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.SQLRef.html)

You will find a great amount of examples in RDS documentation also - [Importing and Exporting Data From a MySQL DB Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html):

Comment: *"Replication from newer masters to older slaves may be possible, but is generally not supported."* -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html I suspect it's worth a try, though, for a short-term application like this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I was not aware of it, good to know, thanks! I would probably give it a try anyway :)